# Raspberry Pi (compute module) Keyboard Suddenly Stops Working

Tags: keyboard

I have a raspberry pi and I have been using it for a couple of hours with no issues, then suddenly they keyboard does not work, I have rebooted the pi, but when I get to the login screen I can't do anything since they keyboard isn't working. I know the keyboard works b/c if I plug into my mac, I can use the keyboard just fine. I was and still using a 12V supply at 3A. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is this a wired (i.e. USB keyboard) or a wireless keyboard? If it is a wireless keyboard, is it Bluetooth or something else?

Comment: @PhilB. it is wired

Comment: I just tried using another keyboard, and the same issue arises

Comment: 2 things: 1) Have you tried using a different USB port? 2) What kind of power supply are you using for your rPi (and what type of rPi is this - A/A+/B/B+/2B ?). I have seen keyboard malfunctions like this on my Pis when the power supply was not able to provide enough amps - either because the supply was crappy (cheap HTC clones) or because the Pi and its peripherals needed too much power (in case of an rPi 2 with USB mouse/keyboard and Wifi dongle)

Comment: @PhilB. I am using a pi compute module, so I only have 1 USB port. I took out all other connections except for an HDMI and canbus. I changed the power supply, but it is 12 V, so it should be plenty be enough.

Comment: I would update your post to clarify that you are talking about a Pi Compute Model. I have no expertise with those so I won't be too helpful, but if you could provide specifics on the 12V supply you use (e.g. Amp ratings) others might be able to help you along.

Answer (score 1):

It was a hardware issue, a delicate wire on the prototype board had come off, quick soldering fixed the issue.

Comment: Hurray for fixing your own problem ! :)